# How to reuse same HTML page between components with different routing?

Tags: angular

I have a Buttons component where there is Add Item, Edit Item and Delete Item buttons. I want to use the same layout for other pages `e.g. ./item, ./bags` (where it will be Add Bag, Edit Bag and Delete Bag), and these buttons will be able to route to the correct forms to fill in the details. `e.g. ./item_form, ./bag_form.`

Is there a way I can reuse the same component in other pages, and in these pages I can specify the names of the buttons and where it routes to?

I've tried searching for ways to do this, but I only came up with the idea to use a bunch of if loops on this buttons component, and to check where the previous page is and route accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using Rokas solution.

The following code will create 6 button 3 for each type, item and bags, links to an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-example-57221289

Define your reusable component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-button',
  template: `
      <button type="button" routerLink="/{{type}}/edit"> edit {{type}}</button>
      <button type="button" routerLink="/{{type}}/delete"> delete {{type}}</button>
      <button type="button" routerLink="/{{type}}/add"> add {{type}}</button>
  `,
})
export class ActionButtonComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()
type: String

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and use it like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <app-action-button [type]="'item'"></app-action-button>
        <app-action-button [type]="'bags'"></app-action-button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent  {
}
```

Comment: Note, this would create 6 buttons... And the buttons are missing a type

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Input for that. You will be able to pass a parameter to the component. In this case - pass the name of the button and the URL.

Reffer to [Angular Input documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Comment: @haowjern if you found the answer helpful, upvote. If it solved your problem, accept it.